# How to send Send Pre-signed URL to Telegram Bot Client?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, chat, telegram-bot, telegram-api

How to send Send Pre-signed URL to Telegram Bot? So the Telegram can then directly upload the file to S3 using this URL. This process doesn't involve your server as a middleman for storing the file temporarily.

My current approach involves the following steps:

1. Receive message event which has photo object with photo_size array
2. Get file info using file_Id - this provides file_path
3. Download the file using the file_path locally
4. Get the pre-signed URL and upload the file using that.
5. Delete a file if stored locally (if it exists )

I want to optimize this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.